# CSS diagonal section divider with background image

Tags: html, css, css-transforms

I'm trying to create diagonal lines between sections of my page using transforms. It works perfectly with a background colour, see: http://jsfiddle.net/jme11/D9M2L/ but not with a background image: http://jsfiddle.net/D9M2L/224/ Why is this?

```
section.diagonal {
    background-image: url('image.jpg');
}

.diagonal:before {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-3deg);
    transform: rotate(-3deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 3% 0;
    transform-origin: 3% 0;
    top: 0;
    left: -25%;
    z-index: -1;
    width: 150%;
    height: 75%;
    background: inherit;
}
```

Comment: i changed the url of the image and i saw it worked, although it looks bad because the images don't line up

Comment: The link to your background image is broken. I don't know why you're setting the height to 75%.

Comment: placekitten is failing in low-res images - increase the res to get a valid image + check console logs to check posible problems of this kind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSFiddle is almost working, if you replace http://placekitten.com/200/300 with an url to an image, se this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/D9M2L/226/). I made some changes to the HTML and CSS.

HTML:

```
<header>
    <p>Header</p>
</header>
<section class="diagonal">
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
</section>
<footer>
    <p>Footer</p>    
</footer>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    background-color: #000;
    margin: 0px;
}
p {
    color: white;
}

section {
    position: relative;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
}

section:before {
    position: absolute;
    content:'';
}

footer {
    position: relative;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
}
footer:before {
    position: absolute;
    content:'';
}
footer.diagonal {
    background: black;
}
.diagonal {
    z-index: 1;
    padding: 3em;
}
.diagonal:before {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-3deg);
    transform: rotate(-3deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 3% 0;
    transform-origin: 3% 0;
    top: 0;
    left: -25%;
    z-index: -1;
    width: 150%;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url('http://www.keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/jcrop/demos/demo_files/image1.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your background image is set on your div having `class="diagonal"`.
Your rotation is made on this div pseudo-element `before`.

If you want your background image to rotate, you should add your background image on your pseudo-element and remove it from your div.

Something like below:

```
section.diagonal {
}

.diagonal:before {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-3deg);
    transform: rotate(-3deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 3% 0;
    transform-origin: 3% 0;
    top: 0;
    left: -25%;
    z-index: -1;
    width: 150%;
    height: 75%;
    background-image: url('image.jpg');
}
```